# React Native FBSDK attempts to open `urlScheme` without the defined suffix on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I'm attempting to make my FBSDK support multiple applications so I set my `CFBundleURLSchemes` to be `fb{APP_ID}{suffix}`.
Now when I type `fb{APP_ID}{suffix}://` into Safari the correct app is attempted to be opened, however when I attempt to perform a Facebook log in from within the app I'm getting the following error: `Exception 'fb{APP_ID} is not registered as a URL scheme. Please add it in you Info.plist' was thrown while invoking logInWithPermissions...`

Notice that `react-native-fbsdk` is attempting to open the app with the URL scheme without the provided suffix.

Any sort of help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I used the `urlScheme` without the suffix. The fix for this is:

`CFBundleURLSchemes` should be `fb{APP_ID}{suffix}` and `FacebookUrlSchemeSuffix` in `Info.plist` should be `suffix`